# I'm getting SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN for my www subdomain

Tags: nginx, ssl

Server: Ubuntu, nginx.

I have a domain `example.com` registered at namecheap.com and configured at DigitalOcean.
I have `CNAME` record for `www` subdomain:

```
www.example.com. 1800 IN CNAME example.com.
```

Here is my `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` file content:

```
# HTTP - redirect all requests to HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS - serve HTML from /usr/share/nginx/html, proxy requests to /parse/
# through to Parse Server

server {
    listen               80;
    server_name          www.example.com;

    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443;
        server_name example.com;

        root /home/example/website;
        index index.html index.htm;

        ssl on;
        # Use certificate and key provided by Let's Encrypt:
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

        # Config (http://www.westphahl.net/blog/2012/01/03/setting-up-https-with-nginx-and-startssl/)
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000;
        add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;

        # Pass requests for /parse/ to Parse Server instance at localhost:1337
        location /parse/ {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:1337/;
                proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

}
```

However, when I'm trying to open `www.example.com` Firefox shows `SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN` "Your connection is not secure" error.

How to fix that?

**ANSWER**: Thanks to all suggesters, issuing an SSL certificate to `www` subdomain did the trick.

Here is a command for Let's Encrypt:

```
./letsencrypt-auto certonly --standalone -d example.com -d www.example.com
```

Comment: Nginx setup looks ok, so best guess is your certificates aren't set up properly. Edit the main post to add a link to the actual website if you want further help. You can always edit it later to remove it.

Comment: @Tim, thanks for the reply, please see post edited. I used Let's Encrypt for generating the cert, as described in this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-a-parse-app-to-parse-server-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Next time, please read the entire error message from Firefox. It tells you what the issue is - the certificate is only valid for `andreygordeev.com`. You are accessing `www.andreygordeev.com`.

Comment: @JennyD I've read the entire error message. It's unclear to me why redirect I configured doesn't work

Comment: The SSL connection is established before the redirect happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Output from Chrome's Warning Page

> This server could not prove that it is **www.example.com**; its security certificate is from **example.com**. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.

The certificate has been issued to the top level domain, `example.com`, but not the the subdomain `www.exmample.com`.

If the ssl issuer says that they are supposed to give you www, check with them for more information.

Note that this warning is coming at the SSL handshake level, and is before the request ever reaches the nginx server for processing.

Comment: Shouldn't the server redirect the user to the top domain then, as described in config? Since the top level domain has the certificate, everything should be fine.

Comment: @AndreyGordeev If you connect via HTTP, sure. If you connect via HTTPS you would need to have a valid certificate for the client to successfully connect.  Why not just create a cert that is valid for both?

Comment: @Andrey, this warning comes at the SSL handshake level, before you even get to the nginx process. If you were to bypass this security warning, then you would be redirected.

Comment: [Most Issuers](https://www.ssls.com/ssl-certificates/comodo-positivessl) will certify both the top level domain, and www. You will need to pay extra for other subdomains.

Comment: @MattClark why SSL handshake occurs when I try to connect to HTTP version?

Comment: @AndreyGordeev Because on port 80 the only thing you do is to redirect to the HTTPS version of the site. Please go back and read the documentation for nginx so that you actually understand what you are doing.

Comment: @AndreyGordeev No you didn't. You redirected to the HTTPS version of whatever hostname was used.